# Create snowflake view for a csv file stored on S3

Tags: view, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-stage

A csv file test_data.csv has been uploaded to S3. An external stage (S3_data) has been created under database=DEV and schema=helper

I am trying to create a view under database=DEV and schema=testing for the above data

I tried as below:

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS  DEV.TESTING.external_data_view AS
SELECT * FROM DEV.helper.@S3_data/data/test_data(FILE_FORMAT => csv_semicolon_textqual);
```

I get the following error:
Syntax error: unexpected '@S3_data/data/test_data'.

Comment: You can’t create a view over external data, you need to create an external table